# Need to understand this quick sort

Tags: data-structures, quicksort

I am having a real difficult time understanding quick sort. Here is my understanding so far

1. We select a pivot
2. All elements less than pivot go on the left of the pivot
3. All elements more than the pivot go on the right
4. Use recursion to continue this process

Now my problem is that I do not understand how to continue with the last step which is the recursion. I have the following so far. I just want a very basic one. The array will not have duplicates

```
void quickSort(int *ptr,int lowindex , int highindex)
{
    int left = lowindex ;
    int right = highindex;
    int pivot = ptr[rand()%highindex];

    while(left < right)
    {
        while(ptr[left] < pivot)
        {
            left++;
        }
        while(ptr[right] > pivot)
        {
            right--;
        }

        //Now swap the two
        int temp = ptr[left];
        ptr[left] = ptr[right];
        ptr[right] = temp;
    }

    std::cout << "Current Array is :  ";
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
     {
         std::cout << ptr[i] << ","  ;
     }
    std::cout << "\n";

        //How to add  recursion ?
}
```

Also is there a chance for `while(left < right)` loop to get stuck - i.e left and right do not change so it keeps on looping? if so how should i handle it ?

Comment: What hapens when `ptr[left]` and `ptr[right]` both point to values equal to the pivot?

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
int pivot = ptr[rand()%highindex];
```

Should be

```
int pivot = ptr[lowindex+rand()%(highindex-lowindex+1)];
```

assuming that the active range is between `lowindex` and `highindex`.  But even so you will get the problem that you don't know if pivot belongs to the left or to the right part, it's easier to pick it from a fixed position, like `pivot=ptr[lowindex]`.

One of your comparison operations should include equality, like

```
  while( ptr[left] <= pivot )
```

At the end you will find the `left` pointer beyond the pivot, and to the right of the `right` pointer.  In this case you must not do the swap operation.

```
    if( left < right ){ // swap
```

After the partitioning you need to make sure the pivot value ends up between both sections

```
swap( ptr[lowindex /*pivot*/], ptr[right] );
```

Finally for recursion you add at the end of the function something like this:

```
quickSort( ptr, lowindex, right-1 );
quickSort( ptr, left, highindex );
```

While the general concept appears rather simple, the details are a bit tricky to get right.  Be prepared for some debugging.  Hope this helps.